# how to enter an larger integer value(more than 10 digits) in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I created a model like

```
rails g model Office name:string location:string phone_no:integer
```

Then if I give values to phone_no of 10 digits it shows an ERROR like

> **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column**

How can I give more than 10 digits?

So how can I overcome this....!

Answer (score 3):

I've always used `string` type column in database for holding phone numbers. You can always call `.to_i` on them later on if you for some reason need to have an int-value but I usually don't.

**Pros** are that you can have a `+` character in it's form field for defining area code.

**Cons** are that you might need to validate numericality of the field in forms.

Comment: Also good for leading '0' and similar

Comment: +1 because this is best practice for phone numbers or other types of data that have digits, but aren't actually used for some sort of calculation.

Comment: I agree that phone numbers are conceptually a string that just happens to contain digits, and should be represented as such.

Answer (score 1):

Integer (4 bytes) has maximum value range :

```
-2147483648  ->  2147483647
0  ->  4294967295 (unsigned )
```

You are getting this error due to overflow. You can use [bigint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types) instead, which has 8 bytes and you shall be fine.

```
-9223372036854775808  ->  9223372036854775807
0  ->  18446744073709551615 (unsigned)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `mysql` then you can use `bigint` like this:

```
change_column :user, :mobile, :int8, :limit => 8
```

this `limit => 8` will make it bigint.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use "change_column :model, :col, :double".  This works on a MySQL db (but i wish the project had used postgres).